# QGIS plugin select and edit feature attribute

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm looking for a QGIS plugin that can change attributes (attribute table) of features on a vector layer by selecting them with the mouse.

I found this plugin "SelectTools": https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SelectTools/
But I want select shapes and want to change the value of one field directly by selecting.

Does someone know if this exists?

If this does't exists is it possible to write this with a plugin?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is hard to understand what do you want. If you want to edit attributes of a single feature at once - make only needed layer selectable and make it editable. Use _Identify_ tool on the feature you wan to edit - attribute window for your feature will appear - edit what you need. If you want to edit attributes of more than one feature - select them with selection tool and open _Field calculator_ to make your edits.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [QuickMultiAttributeEdit plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/QuickMultiAttributeEdit/). This is the work flow:

1. Load a vector layer.
2. Select some features.
3. Press F12 (or click the plugin button).
4. Select the field you want to edit and set the new value for selected features.
5. Click OK and save the edits.

[image: QuickMultiAttributeEdit plugin]